# Rigorous treatment of Ostrogradsky's instability theorem?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

The [Ostrogradsky instability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrogradsky_instability) says that if a Lagrangian depends on more than the position and velocity, the corresponding Hamiltonian is unbounded below. This has been suggested as a reason why you don't generally see PDEs beyond order 2.

However, most references are from physics and the rigor is lacking a bit.   Is there a rigorous introduction to the Ostrogradsky instability theorem from a mathematician's perspective?